# How to Gouraud shading with diffuse lighting in WebGl?

Tags: javascript, opengl, glsl, webgl, shading

I stuck with implementing Gouraud smooth shading. I'm missing something and I need help.

First about diffuse lighting. To get diffuse light I'm using this formula:

*Id * Kd * max( dot(N,L), 0.0)*

I should get my diffuse color and I will add it to my ambient color.

Next shading. Gouraud shading is a shading per vertex.
I found Gouraud shading algorithm in this [lectures](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs155/Lecture_16.pdf)

As I understood this algorithm:

1. Determine the normal at each polygon vertex

```c
vec3 N = mat3(normalMatrix) * normals;
```

2. Apply an illumination model to each vertex to
   calculate the vertex intensity

```
float labertian = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
vec4 color = vec4(intensityAmbientColor * ambientColor
                 + intensityDiffuseColor * diffuseColor * labertian, 1.0);
```

3. Linearly interpolate the vertex intensities over
   the surface polygon

```
v_color = color;
```

This is the output image

[image: output image]

What do I missing here?
vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec3 coordinates;
attribute vec3 normals;

/** MVP */
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
// uniform mat4 viewModelMatrixl

/** LIGHT */
uniform vec3 ambientColor;
uniform float intensityAmbientColor;

uniform vec3 diffuseColor;
uniform float intensityDiffuseColor;

uniform vec3 cameraCoordinates;
uniform vec3 lightCoordinates;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
    viewMatrix *
    modelMatrix *
    vec4(coordinates, 1.0);

  vec3 surfaceWorldPosition = (
    viewMatrix
    * modelMatrix
    * vec4(coordinates, 1.0)
  ).xyz;

  vec3 L = lightCoordinates - surfaceWorldPosition;
  vec3 V = cameraCoordinates - surfaceWorldPosition;
  vec3 N = mat3(normalMatrix) * normals;

  float labertian = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
  v_color = vec4(intensityAmbientColor * ambientColor
                 + intensityDiffuseColor * diffuseColor * labertian, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```c
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

Comment: If you want smooth shading you will have to do it in the fragment shader to benefit from interpolated normals. I'll write a more complete answer if not done already when I have access to a computer

Comment: @Zouch I checked [this example](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jacobson/phong-demo/) and there gouraud shading implemented in vertex shader and just color was interpolated.

Comment: Yes, but it is not "smooth" shading. You can get "smoother" result by computing "smooth" normals as LJᛃ  stated it in his answer. You can also subdivide the mesh (to get more triangles). But in the end, you will never get smooth shading. For that you need to interpolate your normals (which is an automatic process done by the GPU when rasterizing) and use those interpolated normals for your shading in the fragment shader.

Comment: @Zouch in case if I want to subdivide mesh I need to change my vertices data, right? So, and as I understood from LJᛃ answer and articles from net that whole idea in shading is how to compute normals. Of course there is a thing with math in a fragment shader, but still?

Comment: What @Zouch is referring to is per-pixel lighting which is a separate concept that requires averaged normals as well, Also I'd like to refute that "gouraud shading is not "smooth" shading" as per-vertex gouraud shading is commonly referred to as smooth shading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gouraud shading is nothing more than averaging your vertex normals, usually this is part of mesh importers/exporters/converters, you can do it manually, however if your mesh isn't indexed you'd need to reindex it first to find the shared vertices, then average the normals across them. Right now you seem to render an unindexed mesh where each vertex is unique in relation to *one* face.

> An estimate to the surface normal of each vertex in a polygonal 3D model is either specified for each vertex or found by averaging the surface normals of the polygons that meet at each vertex.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading

Comment: Then, the issue is not in glsl code? Okay
I download this mesh and parse it with webpack-obj-loader. 
I'm using indices and vertices to draw elements, vertexNormal from parsed object I'm passing as normals attribute. 

I don't understand how can I have "averaging your vertex normals" if every time in vertex shader passed data for one vertex and you cannot get nearest vetrex data.

Comment: How to index unindexed mesh? And how understand that my mesh is not indexed?

Comment: Averaging the normals is an offline process, done once on the CPU, you can't do it in the vertex shader. You'd need to find all vertices that have the same position(or rather within some threshold due to floating point precision) and average their normals together, or you know ... just export the mesh accordingly ;)

Comment: @StasJus, not sure this is helpful but there is an example of computing vertex normals based on shared positions [in this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-geometry-lathe.html). It sound like the file you loaded happened to have been generated with flat normals. Maybe try just loading a different obj file?

Comment: Does this mean that I need to loop through my faces and take a few faces and find the average normal between them? And if I want flat shading, Do I need to find the average normal for a face. Am I right?

Comment: And DOes this happens at js side,before buffering attribute data?